# How to avoid scrollbar without using max-width? Issue with MUI Drawer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a UL element with some list elements inside, these list elements grow in width when hovered. Problem is that when the list element grows it creates a horizontal scrollbar.

I can fix this issue by setting a `max-width: 80vw` on the UL element but I'm also using the MUI Drawer which when collapsed causes a horizontal scrollbar in the root element.

It's a pretty specific issue and I don't think it's solvable with just CSS, I think I have to set the `max-width` of the UL based on the collapsed status of the MUI drawer:

`max-width: calc(100vw - 65px)` for non collapses and `max-width: calc(100vw - 124px)` when the Drawer is collapsed. This way the UL doesn't overflow the root. But if there's a way to do that with CSS then I would prefer that.

I've created a codesandbox if someone wants to give it a go:

https://codesandbox.io/s/minidrawer-material-demo-forked-3vc46?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I don't see anything growing in width, only change of color.

Comment: @AHaworth sorry I was messing around in the sandbox, should've created a fork. But I think I've resolved it with `flex-grow`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked this solution into my project yet, but it seems that using `flex-grow` does the trick.

https://codesandbox.io/s/minidrawer-material-demo-forked-2wxm6?file=/demo.tsx:952-1001

```
  someClassList: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: '200px',
    margin: '8px',
    background: 'red',
    listStyle: 'none',
    transition: 'all 0.2s ease-in',
  },

  someHoverClass: {
    background: 'pink!important',
    flexGrow: 4,
  }
```

No need to set any max widths. The list items all have `flex-grow: 1` and when hovered the value changes. Flex then shrinks the other elements so everything still fits in the UL without creating any scrollbars. Also works with the drawer open or closed.